# C# Threading: What's the difference between Block and WaitSleepJoin?

Tags: c#, multithreading

This is in reference to a thread's state.

Is there a difference between a thread being Blocked and a thread being in a WaitSleepJoin state, or are they one in the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`ThreadState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstate.aspx) enumeration (`System.Threading`) doesn't have a `Blocked` state.

From MSDN:

- `WaitSleepJoin` - The thread is blocked. This could be the result of calling Thread.Sleep or Thread.Join, of requesting a lock — for example, by calling Monitor.Enter or Monitor.Wait — or of waiting on a thread synchronization object such as ManualResetEvent.

The [`System.Diagnostics.ThreadState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.threadstate.aspx) enumeration doesn't have a `Blocked` or a `WaitSleepJoin` member.